# Convert PHP array to Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I'm trying to convert a PHP array to coldfusion I'm stumped and was hoping you all could help. Below is the line of code I'm trying to convert:

```
$round[$i][$j]["Home"]=$home[$j];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more info please let me know.
I've read solutions to the other 2 questions regarding this, but they don't seem relevant.
Regards,

Jay

Comment: Array syntax is similar in CF, just no `$`. It would help to know what code you've tried and what was the result. You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50513120/edit) link to add your code snippet to the question.

Comment: It goes more or less the same way it is done in php. `round[i][j]["Home"]=home[j];` Also, the index starts on `1` not `0`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, what have you tried, and what issues are/have you ran into? Right now we can only guess what your understanding of PHP and CMFL data structures are. You may want to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I figured out what I needed to for the arrays. Thanks!

Comment: If you think the solution would be helpful to someone else, post the final code as an answer. Otherwise, delete the thread (since it currently has no answers).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user solved the problem and there are no posted answers,